# When upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 does bind require an upgrade?

Tags: 22.04

I had DNS running on Ubuntu 18.04. I upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 and retained my original DNS configuration. Now, on 22.04 bind9 won’t start. Do I need to upgrade bind, too?

Comment: Read your logs. `sudo journalctl -u named` should give you some hints to what is happening.

Comment: You're colliding with `systemd-dnsmasq`, read `man systemd-dnsmasq`.

Comment: @waltinator Please leave an answer if you believe this is the solution. Telling someone to read a man page is *not* very polite, and if that's what we're here for we could replace AU with `man`.